# Create histogram using matplotlib in python using input file

Tags: python, matplotlib, file-io, histogram

I have a txt file with 5 columns e.g. 'data.txt':

[data.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LxUf.png)

I want to create a histogram using data from col 2 (age) as x-axis and have the entire column counted as 'count' for the y-axis

I am currently using the code below but i'm only getting weird results

```
with open('Players.txt') as f:
   v = np.loadtxt(f, delimiter= ' ', dtype="str", skiprows=1, usecols=2)

plt.hist(v, bins=100)
plt.xlabel('Age')
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.title('Histogram of Age')

plt.show()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Can you provide some better input data?

Comment: Added an image of data now!

Comment: why data as picture? - if you already imported your file via numpy, please use an output of v or v[:10] or whatever to show, with what kind of data you're struggling around.       However, as you already reduced the import to column 2, I assume `plt.hist(v)` should do for a first plot.      And why do you import your data as dtype = 'str'? Leave it away, I'd recommend.

Comment: picture was used to give a snapshot of working data file on this page. I've made the changes mentioned but still return "ValueError: could not convert string to float:"